# Using Custom Google Map in my Web App is legal or not?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-mobile

I am developing a web application, i have following uses of google maps

- List some facilities like film theater in map as thumbnail with contact details (i have kept latitude and longitude in my database)
- show route and directions from user location to that facility

is this legal to use in an application for public use..?

if there is no problem with that, please suggest your developing ideas...

thanks in advance....

Comment: asking for legal advice here seems dangerous at best - consult a lawyer.  The terms of service are available and fairly straightforward IMHO.

Comment: WRT the TOS, there are some related FAQ entries @ https://developers.google.com/maps/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Showing the facilities will likely be done via the Maps API and adding markers

  - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Markers
- showing route/directions will use the Directions API

  - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsRequests

Comment: thanks James.. is there any legal restriction for using those..?